# Qt Creator - How can I set the background color of a tooltip to be different than the widget?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, background-color, tooltip

I am working on a GUI and I've run into a problem.  If I set a button, label, or other widget to have a background color, the tooltip for that widget also takes the same background color. I tried editing the style sheet for the tooltip specifically and setting a different background color but it doesn't work. I also tried editing the palette for the widget but changing the color scheme for the tooltip background or text doesn't work either. Is there another way I can do this? I'd like to have consistency between all my tooltips.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this to style a `QToolTip` in general.

```css
QToolTip { color: #fff; background-color: #000; border: none; }
```

When you need to style `QToolTips` specifically, based on their parent widget you can use following syntax:

```css
ParentWidgetName QToolTip { color: #333; background-color: #1c1c1c; border: none; }
```

[Reading this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) will help you further.

Comment: I tried adding that code to the stylesheet and changed it to the background color I want, but it still doesn't change the tooltip background when I run my application. Am I missing something? Where should I be adding that code?

Comment: I got it! Just had to set it in my actual code instead of going into the widget stylesheet!

Comment: You can either have a separate file with all your `css` contents and apply it to the whole application at run time. Search Stackoverflow for related questions, you will find a way how to do it. Of course you have Qt documentation as well to refer further.

Comment: That doesn't work. I tired doing `QApplication::setStyleSheet("QToolTip{background-color:white}")` and `myWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color:red")` because I wanted to make the widget red and the tooltip white, but the tooltip was also red.